# How to create small maven project using command line

Tags: java, xml, maven

I was trying to create new maven project to check whether maven is working.

So I tried this.

```
mvn archetype:create <br/>
  -DgroupId=your.simple.java.gid <br/>
  -DartifactId=your-simple-java-aid
```

But Sadly I got a huge error saying

> NoClassDefFoundError for org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamReader

Please help me with this. 

I tried various question but they all helping to create projects using IDE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `create` use `generate`.

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DgroupId=your.simple.java.gid  -DartifactId=your-simple-java-aid
```

This will create the project in `Interactive mode`. It will ask you different input from you while generating your project.

You can ignore the `Interactive mode` by setting it to `false`. This will be batch mode.

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DgroupId=your.simple.java.gid  -DartifactId=your-simple-java-aid -DinteractiveMode=false
```

You can take a look here for more details: [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Comment: :( Sadly I'm getting the same error? Also no input asking :(

Comment: @pippilongstocking Do you have connectivity to the internet. It needs to download some dependent jars/poms for completing this. You can follow the instruction provided at the maven official site. You are probably missing the depedency jar for `XmlStreamReader`. Check this out: [`Link`](http://www.1maven.com//classname-packaging?pk=javax.xml.stream&cl=XMLStreamReader).

Comment: @pippilongstocking This solution should work. Delete your current m2 repo and make sure Maven can access the internet (if you are behind a proxy it needs to be configured)

Comment: I activated proxy. Last time was my mistake. But still no.. Can you tell me where to find m2 files. I mean I searched all m2 s in my PC. But there are only eclipse ones are there.

Comment: @pippilongstocking this is your `<user_home>/.m2/repository/`.

Comment: <user_home> ? Is this c/Users/Account_Name

Comment: @pippilongstocking looks like you are using Windows. Try this `cd c:\Users\Account_Name\.m2`. This is a hidden for folder, so might not be visible from explorer.

Comment: THANK YOU.. THANK YOU.. THANK YOU.. You are a life saviour. If you came to my country please let me know. I owe you a meal.. Thanks once again. Worked like a charm.